# Share (object type) instances by reference

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, pass-by-reference

Can I share an object (type) instance between two contexts, for example two other type instances?

I'm trying to spice up my Oracle PL/SQL development up a bit by using object types for object oriented programming, hoping to get a better separation of concern and *almost* get to a point of inversion of control.

However, for that last step, ideally I'd like objects to be able to have references to other objects. For instance, I'd like to pass some TLogic type a TLogger instance so it can log output to it. By passing it in the constructor, I can determine whether I want to give it some null logger, or one that logs to a table, to dbms_output, or in the case below, to one of its own attributes.

My naive approach, implemented below, uses an `in out` parameter in the constructor of TLogic to pass the TLogger instance to it. The code below runs, but the test reveals that I actually have a copy of the TLogger. I suspect this copying happens when I assign the TLogger to the Logger attribute.

```
-- Rig up
create or replace type TLogger force as object (
  Output varchar2(4000),
  member procedure LogMessage(p_Msg varchar2)  
);

create or replace type body TLogger as
  member procedure LogMessage(p_Msg varchar2) is
  begin
    self.Output := self.Output || p_Msg || crlf;
  end;
end;
/

create or replace type devvanessa.TLogic as object (
  Logger TLogger,
  member procedure DoSomeWork
);

create or replace type body devvanessa.TLogic as
  member procedure DoSomeWork is
  begin
    Logger.LogMessage('Working really hard. It''s ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') || ', almost beer-''o-clock');
  end;
end;
/

-- Test
declare
  v_Logger TLogger;
  v_Logic TLogic;
begin
  v_Logger := new TLogger('');
  v_Logic := new TLogic(v_Logger);
  v_Logic.DoSomeWork();

  -- The actual log exists in the logger in logic, which is apparently a copy.
  dbms_output.put_line('Their logger: ' || v_Logic.Logger.Output);
  -- But "My" logger is empty.
  dbms_output.put_line('My logger: ' || v_Logger.Output);
end;
/

-- Tear down
drop type body TLogic;
drop type TLogic;
drop type body TLogger;
drop type TLogger;
```

I found a bit about `ref` and `deref`, and I was able to change the parameter and the attribute to a `ref TLogger`, but after that I still wasn't able to successfully pass in a TLogger and use that actual instance.

When trying to get a reference to the instance I made, I get `Expression is of the wrong type`.

Later on, when using the reference, I also get `Navigation through REF variables is not supported in PL/SQL`. I understand why, and I think I can solve the error message by using `select deref(myref) into myvar from dual`, but I don't think that will solve the problem, because I suspect it will just give me another copy. I just couldn't get to the point where I can actually confirm this.

```
create or replace type devvanessa.TLogic as object (
  Logger ref TLogger, -- Ref here
  member procedure DoSomeWork
);

-- Test
declare
  v_Logger ref TLogger; -- Ref here
  v_Logic TLogic;
begin
  -- "Expression is of the wrong type
  v_Logger := new TLogger('');
  v_Logic := new TLogic(v_Logger);
  v_Logic.DoSomeWork();

  -- "Navigation through REF variables is not supported in PL/SQL"
  dbms_output.put_line('My logger: ' || v_Logger.Output);
  dbms_output.put_line('Their logger: ' || v_Logic.Logger.Output);
end;
/
```

So my question: is it possible to share the actual same instance of an object type between the caller (test code) and another type instance, in such a way that I can manipulate it in both contexts?

Comment: *"I'm trying to spice up my Oracle PL/SQL development up a bit by using object types for object oriented programming"*. I don't think Oracle objects are up to full-on OOP. The lack of private attributes and functions is fatal to proper encapsulation. However it is possible to achieve *"separation of concerns"* and even *"inversion of control"* through good PL/SQL design. After all, these are not OO concepts - both [date from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#Origin) [the 1970s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control#Background) .

Comment: @APC Thanks.You're right, they are not OOP concepts, but typically implemented like that. Also I'm not aware of other ways to achieve this in PL/SQL. There is no proper way, to my knowledge, for specifying a callback or something like that, except maybe passing strings of code that can be executed using `execute immediate`. So I don't _have to_ use types if there is a better way. I'm open to alternatives. :-)